# How to get pre-selected(default) value in Autocomplete (Material UI)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

How do I get preselected value in Autocomplete (default value).

The use case is: The user lands on the page, types in the category name and hit the save button without changing parent category dropdown (the onChange event will not fired in this case).

```
  const handleOnAutoCompleteInputChange = (
    e: React.SyntheticEvent,
    value: any,
    reason: string
  ) => {
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      parentId: value?.id,
    }));
  };

 <Autocomplete             
              size="small"
              sx={{ width: 300 }}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
              getOptionKey={(option) => option.id}
              options={parentCategory}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Parent Category" />
              )}
              onChange={handleOnAutoCompleteInputChange}
              isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
              defaultValue={{
                name: "Root",
                id: "4086deae-7144-40f1-99ab-cc9cf862eb8a",
              }}
            />
```

[image]